# Why a python function fails when I set the parameters with a range loop?

Tags: python, loops

I'm new to Python and i'm trying to solve the coin change problem with a script. I managed to make a function that returns a dictionary with the number of each coin used to give the optimum change. The function is as follows:

```
def optimal_change(c, l_coins):
    ncoins=[]
    dicts=[]
    l_coins.reverse()
    if c==0:
        return 0
    for i in range(0, len(l_coins)):
        x=0
        y=c
        d={}
        for j in range(i, len(l_coins)):
            while y-l_coins[j]>=0:
                y=y-l_coins[j]
                x=x+1
                if l_coins[j] not in d:
                    d[l_coins[j]]=1
                else:
                    d[l_coins[j]]+=1
        ncoins.append(x)
        dicts.append(d)
    return dicts[ncoins.index(min(ncoins))]
```

The function is probably very unefficient but it works when individual parameters are given. The problem is that when i execute it with a range loop that sets different parameters, the pair positions give weird results. For example:

```
l_coins = [1, 3, 4, 5]
for c in range(1, 10):
    print(c, optimal_change(c, l_coins))
```

outputs:

```
1 {1: 1}
2 {}
3 {3: 1}
4 {}
5 {5: 1}
6 {4: 1}
7 {4: 1, 3: 1}
8 {5: 1}
9 {5: 1, 4: 1}
```

I know it is not a matter of even and odd values but even and odd positions.
Can someone tell me what's happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `l_coins` is a list, which is a mutable type in Python, the `reverse()` method changes the object outside of the function scope. In other words, you keep reversing `l_coins` back and forth, which breaks the algorithm. A quick fix would be to create a copy of `l_coins` inside the function, then reverse the copy instead of the original. Here is a proof of concept that resolves the original issue.

```
def optimal_change(c, l_coins):
    ncoins=[]
    dicts=[]
    l_copy = list(l_coins)
    l_copy.reverse()
    if c==0:
        return 0
    for i in range(0, len(l_copy)):
        x=0
        y=c
        d={}
        for j in range(i, len(l_copy)):
            while y- l_copy [j]>=0:
                y=y- l_copy [j]
                x=x+1
                if l_copy [j] not in d:
                    d[l_copy [j]]=1
                else:
                    d[l_copy [j]]+=1
        ncoins.append(x)
        dicts.append(d)
    return dicts[ncoins.index(min(ncoins))]



l_coins = [1, 3, 4, 5]
for c in range(1, 10):
    print(c, optimal_change(c, l_coins))
```